# How to keep figures before the references in a paper in LaTeX?

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a paper with 30 figures. I added all the figures before conclusion section. But after compiling the document, 10 figures are placed into the middle of the document and after the references. I applied `\begin{figure}[!htbp]` in the first of the figures definition.

How can I force the figure to stay in the place where I defined it in the paper, for example before  the references or conclusion sections?

Comment: you can't "force" a float to stay where you put it, if there isn't enough space for the float there.  the answer is not to put your figures and things inside a float, but rather inside a `\parbox` or the like, using `\captionof` from the `capt-of` (or `caption`) package to define the content of the box.  when you do that, the outside (non-)floats run over the end of the page, producing "overfull vbox" errors, and you can track them that way.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can add a
    \clearpage
before your references. It will flush all the figures up to that point.

Comment: This creates weird spacing in references and main text

Comment: The `\clearpage` command needs to be strategically placed. In my case, the order of figure and reference is messed up by a small paragraph with a large figure. Instead of placing `\clearpage` before the reference, I placed it before that small paragraph, and the problem is resolved.

Comment: This works perfectly, thanks